# Importing any 3d model in unreal engine 4 in-game from local disk

Tags: import, virtual-reality, unreal-engine4, fbx, daydream

I want to import a 3d model/mesh inside a game. Kinda like import a mesh from file explorer kinda thing.
Is there any good way to do this? Without much coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to load custom 3D meshes (like .fbx or .obj) that weren't preprocesed by editor first and are not in game folders, and you want to do it at runtime while game is playing.

What I get know from recent reaseach in this topic: UE4 dosen't support any kind of API for loading such meshes, you could legaly use in your game at runtime. There are, of course, existent API for that but it's part of Editor codebase and you are not allowed to use it in game directly, it is restricted by current licence (look at Epic Dev response in [this thread](https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?104122-Importing-FBX-files-In-Game-C-code)).

In this case you could use thrid-party loaders and integrate them in your project or write your own loaders. Loaded meshes can be displayed using [Procedural Mesh Component](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Procedural_Mesh_Component_in_C%2B%2B:Getting_Started).